# IE8 just reloads the page instead of the ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, internet-explorer-8

I have such form:

```
    <form action="Home/Index" id="contactform" onSubmit="javascript:postContactForm();return false;">    
    <p>
     <input class="textfield form-controld" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Name must be 50 characters or less" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="The Name should not contain special characters" data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+$" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" />
     <div class="error-holder"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    </p>

   //some more fields
    </form>
```

Simple post funciton:

```
function postContactForm() {

        if (!$("#contactform").valid())
            return false;

        //doing post
    }
```

I tested the form it is working with any browser including mobile browsers.

But on IE8 whatever the form is valid or not browser just reloads the form + added the post params to the query string.

How do you fix that?

**UPDATE:**
Was trying to add `method="POST"` in that case form `still reloaded` in IE8 but without injecting params in to query string.

Comment: Close form tag nicely `</from> ` to `</form>`

Comment: @Anup on real site it is right so I fix it here as well

Comment: I haven't used `on[event]=...` for a long time anymore, so I can't tell if the following could be a problem in IE, but you don't need the `javascript:` there because it is already known that it is javascript  (I even don't know if `javascript:` is valid at that place). Does the problem still exists if you just write `onSubmit="postContactForm();return false;"` ?

Comment: @t.niese that's horrible advice. jQuery, which OP is using already normalizes events across browsers. OP, Which version of jQuery are you using anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i know that the OP is using jQuery, but as `onSubmit="javascript:postContactForm();return false;"` is used in posted code instead of jQuery a quick check would be to remove the `javascript:`. If it then still fails there is most likely an exception that happens in the `postContactForm()`.

Comment: Looks like it is doesent matter `onSubmit="javascript:postContactForm();return false;"` OR `onSubmit="postContactForm();return false;"` OR EVEN `onSubmit="return postContactForm();"`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `onSubmit` attribute to *return* the value of your function.

```
<form action="Home/Index" id="contactform" onSubmit="return postContactForm();">
```

Or if you want to use the `javascript:` notation that would be

```
<form action="Home/Index" id="contactform" onSubmit="javascript: return postContactForm();">
```

---

A full working example below (tested in FireFox, IE7 and IE8)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postContactForm() {
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form action="Home/Index" id="contactform" onSubmit="return postContactForm();">    
    <p>
        <input class="textfield form-controld" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Name must be 50 characters or less" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="The Name should not contain special characters" data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+$" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" />
        <div class="error-holder"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see the update. If it's still not working make sure `!$("#contactform").valid()` is returning `false` and run your markup through a validator to make sure it's not malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rest of your code (the `//doing post`) throws an error in IE8. The form will be submitted in this case, as `return false` won't be reached.